# browserslist@4.14.7: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I am getting below yarn error when run:
npx create-react-app my-awesome-react-app --template typescript

```
error browserslist@4.14.7: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^6 || ^7 || ^8 || ^9 || ^10 || ^11 || ^12 || >=13.7". Got "13.3.0"
error Found incompatible module.
```

Any idea how will this be resolved?

Comment: Use a version of node that's supported?

Comment: my node version is 14.2.0

Comment: The message says you're running 13.3.0, so it might be worth investigating what versions you have installed.

Comment: When I used `node -v` return this: `14.2.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is surely related to npx.

I've just had the same problem using the latest npx.

```
npx -v
10.2.2
```

I updated npm as well as yarn globally on my machine, still no success.

I tried without npx and it solved the problem:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app <project_name>
```

If you don't mind having create-react-app installed globally on your machine, this would be a solution for you, too.